# Click by bounds / coordinates

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I know it is possible for Espresso to click by bounds the way [UiAutomator does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519905/uiautomator-click-on-a-imagebutton-with-no-text-or-content-desc). (x and y coordinates) I have read through the documentation but I can't seem to find it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**
I found [this link](https://android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git/docs/javadocs/apidocs/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/action/Tapper.html), but no examples how to use it, My main concern with this is the `UiController` is or how to use it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Espresso has the [`GeneralClickAction`](http://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/espresso/lib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/action/GeneralClickAction.java), this is the underlying implementation of ViewActions `click()`, `doubleClick()`, and `longClick()`.

The `GeneralClickAction`'s constructor takes a `CoordinatesProvider` as second argument.
So the basic idea is to create a static `ViewAction` getter which provides a custom `CoordinatesProvider`. Something like this:

```
public static ViewAction clickXY(final int x, final int y){
    return new GeneralClickAction(
        Tap.SINGLE,
        new CoordinatesProvider() {
            @Override
            public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {

               final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
               view.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);

               final float screenX = screenPos[0] + x;
               final float screenY = screenPos[1] + y;
               float[] coordinates = {screenX, screenY};

               return coordinates;
            }
        },
        Press.FINGER);
}
```

A general advice with Espresso: instead of looking for documentation (there's virtually none), look at the source code. Espresso is open source and the source code itself is of really good quality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I get a chance to test it out, I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry for the late request for help, but this is not clicking. I am not getting any errors, but it is also not clicking anywhere. Is there anything I don't understand about it?

Comment: One thing to remember is, that x, y are coordinates relative to view left/top, not screen left/top. But else I can't think of more right now. We use this kind of custom CoordinatesProviders a lot and so far didn't run into any issues. You can also try to log screenX/screenY to the logcat and see if the values make any sense.

Comment: So what view is it referring to?

Comment: The view you are performing it on. onView(..).perform(clickXY(10, 20)); The view that is matched by the matcher given to onView.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. Thats what I missunderstood

Comment: @haffax I'd like to use screen absolute coordinates (say, 0,0 of screen). What should I put to `onView(...)` ? I tried `onView(isRoot()). and it failed with no match. Note : I am currently showing dialog in front

Answer (score 15):

The valid answer helped me although that method is deprecated.
Now you have to specify the `inputDevice` (for example `InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE`) and `buttonState` (for example `MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY`

Example in **Kotlin**:

```
companion object {
    fun clickIn(x: Int, y: Int): ViewAction {
        return GeneralClickAction(
                Tap.SINGLE,
                CoordinatesProvider { view ->
                    val screenPos = IntArray(2)
                    view?.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos)

                    val screenX = (screenPos[0] + x).toFloat()
                    val screenY = (screenPos[1] + y).toFloat()

                    floatArrayOf(screenX, screenY)
                },
                Press.FINGER,
                InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE,
                MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

@haffax's answer is great and works well.

However, if you want to click in a certain part of a View that may change from screen to screen, it might be useful to click based on percents (or ratios) as even the dp numbers may not be stable across all screens. So, I made an easy modification to it:

```
    public static ViewAction clickPercent(final float pctX, final float pctY){
    return new GeneralClickAction(
            Tap.SINGLE,
            new CoordinatesProvider() {
                @Override
                public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {

                    final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
                    view.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);
                    int w = view.getWidth();
                    int h = view.getHeight();

                    float x = w * pctX;
                    float y = h * pctY;

                    final float screenX = screenPos[0] + x;
                    final float screenY = screenPos[1] + y;
                    float[] coordinates = {screenX, screenY};

                    return coordinates;
                }
            },
            Press.FINGER);
}
```

I thought I would share it here so others can benefit.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone uses this code, value for pctX and pctY, ranges from 0 to 1.