# Espresso - Set SeekBar

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, seekbar, android-espresso

does anybody know, how to set a seekBar to a specific value or just a click on that view on Espresso UI Testing ?

I just get an exception: Error performing 'single click' on view with id...

```
onView(withId(R.id.FilterPriceMax)).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You might want to give the following code a try:

First you could match the `SeekBar` with its class name:

```
onView(withClassName(Matchers.equalTo(SeekBar.class.getName()))).perform(setProgress(progress));
```

where setProgress(final int progress) is a ViewAction you defined as:

```
public static ViewAction setProgress(final int progress) {
        return new ViewAction() {
            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                seekBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Set a progress on a SeekBar";
            }
            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(SeekBar.class);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: this is a great answer. It's a shame these answers are down voted.

Comment: the 'int progress' argument to setProgress() should be declare final for  use in inner class.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: One of the issues is that it does not set the flag `fromUser` so if you use the flag it will not work.

Comment: what would be the case if you have two seekbars? im getting error that SeekBar has mutli views (2)

Comment: This does work, but not with the `fromUser` flag set :(

Answer (score 21):

I have a custom Seekbar, and also I have multiple Seekbars in my View. I managed do my test with this code below:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_seek_bar)).perform(setProgress(10));
```

and

```
public static ViewAction setProgress(final int progress) {
        return new ViewAction() {
            @Override
            public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                ((MyCustomSeekBar) view).setSelectedProgress(progress);
                //or ((SeekBar) view).setProgress(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Set a progress";
            }

            @Override
            public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                return ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(RangeSeekBar.class);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: What's the RangeSeekbar.class that's mentioned ? can you please recall ..

Answer (score 14):

I use a swipe-action to perform an actual swipe on the `SeekBar`. This makes sure the callback method (`SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener. onProgressChanged`) is called with `fromUser` set to true. It is also more in the line of click testing.

```
public static ViewAction scrubSeekBarAction(int progress) {
    return actionWithAssertions(new GeneralSwipeAction(
            Swipe.SLOW,
            new SeekBarThumbCoordinatesProvider(0),
            new SeekBarThumbCoordinatesProvider(progress),
            Press.PINPOINT));
}

private static class SeekBarThumbCoordinatesProvider implements CoordinatesProvider {
    int mProgress;

    public SeekBarThumbCoordinatesProvider(int progress) {
        mProgress = progress;
    }

    private static float[] getVisibleLeftTop(View view) {
        final int[] xy = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
        return new float[]{ (float) xy[0], (float) xy[1] };
    }

    @Override
    public float[] calculateCoordinates(View view) {
        if (!(view instanceof SeekBar)) {
            throw new PerformException.Builder()
                    .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
                    .withCause(new RuntimeException(String.format("SeekBar expected"))).build();
        }
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
        int width = seekBar.getWidth() - seekBar.getPaddingLeft() - seekBar.getPaddingRight();
        double progress = mProgress == 0 ? seekBar.getProgress() : mProgress;
        int xPosition = (int) (seekBar.getPaddingLeft() + width * progress / seekBar.getMax());
        float[] xy = getVisibleLeftTop(seekBar);
        return new float[]{ xy[0] + xPosition, xy[1] + 10 };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a promising solution but it returns the wrong value on my device.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "wrong value", but if you mean that the progress value after `scrubSeekBarAction` is not the same as you set it, than it seems to help to have a `Thread.sleep(1000)` before (and maybe after) 'scrub...'. I guess it's similar problem like this "perform(click()) is doing a long click" issue.

Comment: I experienced inaccuracy on LG devices API 21-23 (virtual and physical). The swipe was performed correctly (tracing using `Pointer location` in `Developer options`), but the `SeekBar` did not register last ~ 20 % of the swipe regardless of speed, I don't know why. I then changed `GeneralSwipeAction` with `GeneralClickAction` and works great for my case. It's a click instead of swipe. I also added `0.25` to `progress` to be on a safe side as older APIs round down the click/swipe whereas the newer ones round it to the nearest value, though it did not turn out to be necessary so far.

Answer (score 10):

In case you want to check the progress value

```
  public static Matcher<View> withProgress(final int expectedProgress) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, SeekBar>(SeekBar.class) {
      @Override
      public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("expected: ");
        description.appendText(""+expectedProgress);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean matchesSafely(SeekBar seekBar) {
        return seekBar.getProgress() == expectedProgress;
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used this to do some basic testing on seekbar UI components if you don't require specific values. It assumes the 'check()' is based on a 0-100 percentage.

```
onView(withId(R.id.yourSeekBar)).perform(new GeneralClickAction(Tap.SINGLE, GeneralLocation.CENTER_LEFT, Press.FINGER));
onView(withId(R.id.yourSeekBarUserFeedback)).check(matches(withText("0")));

onView(withId(R.id.yourSeekBar)).perform(new GeneralClickAction(Tap.SINGLE, GeneralLocation.CENTER, Press.FINGER));
onView(withId(R.id.yourSeekBarUserFeedback)).check(matches(withText("50")));

onView(withId(R.id.yourSeekBar)).perform(new GeneralClickAction(Tap.SINGLE, GeneralLocation.CENTER_RIGHT, Press.FINGER));
onView(withId(R.id.yourSeekBarUserFeedback)).check(matches(withText("100")));
```

Comment: The `GeneralClickAction()` that takes 3 parameters is declared as deprecated. We are now recommended to use `GeneralClickAction()` that takes 5 parameters, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177590/click-by-bounds-coordinates#48446640